# avro file read with custom schema issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, avro

I am trying to read a avro file with my custom avro schema file but getting an error during parsing the schema file.

My current code:

```
import org.apache.avro.Schema
val schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(new File("/data/core/se/atlas-diganalys/ga/schemas/ga_comviq_web_combo.avsc"))
```

Error:

```
<console>:30: error: not found: type File
       val schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(new File("/data/core/se/atlas-diganalys/ga/schemas/ga_comviq_web_combo.avsc"))
                                                  ^
```

Answer (score 1):

try importing java.io.File first:

```
import org.apache.avro.Schema
import java.io.File

val schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(new File("/data/core/se/atlas-diganalys/ga/schemas/ga_comviq_web_combo.avsc"))
```